# Python - How to post request with loop/read value (payload) from both of 2 columns .txt file?

Tags: python, loops, file

I want to read both columns on my txt file.

Is it possible to read all values from both of 2 columns row per row?

*This is myfile.txt :*

```
1   8
2   15
3   125
0   12
54  0
15  125
54  54
15  25
485 78
```

*This is my post request code:*

```
import requests
with open("myfile.txt", "r") as a_file:
   for line in a_file:
      CurrentRow = int(line.strip())
      url = "url"
      headers = {headers}
      data = {"MyPayload": f"Will-be{CurrentRow[0]}-is{CurrentRow[1]}-ndwiqb"}
      Hasil = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=data)
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: sorry edited misspelled code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A line is both numbers, you can convert it to an `int` directly you need to split and then convert both to int

```
import requests
with open("myfile.txt", "r") as a_file:
   for line in a_file:
      values = line.rstrip().split()
      CurrentRow = int(values[0]), int(values[1]) # << -----
      url = "url"
      headers = {headers}
      data = {"MyPayload": f"Will-be{CurrentRow[0]}-is{CurrentRow[1]}-ndwiqb"}
      Hasil = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=data)
```

Comment: @AndikaFrans You're welcome, don't hesitate to accept/vote up the answer so ;)

Comment: okay. Can you help me for my other question here please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63437414/python-how-to-define-current-json-response-as-integer-value-for-the-next-post

Comment: @AndikaFrans maybe I'll take a look but accepting this one is independant ;)